# After setting mediation in WSO2 API Manager 1.10, I have figured out null point exception and missing credential error. What I have to do?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 APIManager 1.10.
I'd like to call api request using mediation like this.

```
<sequence name="loadbalancer_bycompany" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <property expression="get-property('transport', 'company')"
    name="company" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  <property name="POST_TO_URI" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
  <switch source="$trp:company">
    <case regex="sds">
      <send>
        <endpoint>
          <address trace="disable" uri="https://70.30.182.167:8243/calc/1.0/"/>
        </endpoint>
      </send>
    </case>
    <case regex="etc">
      <send>
        <endpoint>
          <address trace="disable" uri="https://70.30.182.167:9443/calc/1.0/"/>
        </endpoint>
      </send>
    </case>
    <default>
      <send>
        <endpoint>
          <address trace="disable" uri="https://70.30.182.167:9443/carbon/"/>
        </endpoint>
      </send>
    </default>
  </switch>
</sequence>
```

So,I tried to set mediator and then i called api. 
But, I got sometimes error response that is code 900902 missing credential,
sometimes got right response.

At that time, I found logs like this.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 10:45:10,728]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,company,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 10:45:10,735] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} -  Failed to submit the response {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:462)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:493)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:534)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 10:45:10,738] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,company,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>0</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,company,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">&lt;soapenv:Body/>&lt;/soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back</am:description></am:fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:610)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:493)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:534)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:462)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
    ... 18 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 10:45:10,740] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,company,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>0</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,company,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">&lt;soapenv:Body/>&lt;/soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back</am:description></am:fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:534)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,company,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>0</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,company,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">&lt;soapenv:Body/>&lt;/soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back</am:description></am:fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:247)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:215)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:493)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:610)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:462)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
    ... 18 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 10:45:59,370]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler} -  Stat is not enabled {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 10:45:59,374]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /calc/1.0/subtract?x=3&y=1, MessageID: urn:uuid:8f4000dc-b878-4d5f-b310-f0129f2db0a3, Direction: request, INFO = https://70.30.182.167:8243/calc/1.0/, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 10:45:59,390]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler} -  Stat is not enabled {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 10:45:59,395]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failure due to Missing Credentials {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
```

I found this logs repeatedly, so I i made an effort to fix it.
First of all, to remove this error,
NullPointerException
SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)

I figured out code issue in PassThroughHttpSender.java that didn't handle with null case for sourceRequest. And then I found that issue was fixed 
wso2-synapse 
ESBJAVA-3770 Message size based filtering to prevent OOM. (#679)

https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/commit/1aff92c4bad968f78cf38577cbb7c01516475217

So, I added that code into our codes.
And then  NullPointException was disappeared.

And then I tried to remove missing credential error.
So I found this link.
[Authorization Bearer in URL Request using WSO2 API Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523902/authorization-bearer-in-url-request-using-wso2-api-manager)

And I tried to set configure like below link.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Writing+Custom+Handlers

And then Missing credential error was removed.
And then result is right response. 
But I found below log infinitely

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-08 13:20:12,563]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler} -  No authentication context information found on the request - Throttling not applied {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler}
```

I tried to debug SourceHandler and TargetHandler.
and I think connection was created infinitely and wasn't closed all.

I don't know what to do anymore.
So please let me know what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the sample [implementation](https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/48269299/APIAuthenticationHandler.java?version=1&modificationDate=1444375908000&api=v2) provided in [docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Writing+Custom+Handlers). Based on the [APIThrottleHandler](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/throttling/APIThrottleHandler.java#L529) implementation, this warning message would appear if you haven't set the user context within your custom Auth handler. Please check how the default "OAuthAuthenticator" has been written and how the AuthenticationContext getting initialized. You need to do a similar implementation to your custom handler if need to work with throttling.